# COUNT field incorrect or syntax error (no placeholders or PDO)

Tags: php, sql, odbc, ssms

I have this sql server query in a PHP script:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO jobrouter.dbo.zt_ara_sitzungen (newID2, name, datum) 
SELECT MAX(newID2) + 1, $sitzungsname, $sitzungsdatum FROM jobrouter.dbo.zt_ara_sitzungen";
```

If run in SSMS it works perfectly fine, but if I try it in my PHP script, there is this error message:

```
_doQuery: [Error message: Could not execute statement]
[Last executed query: INSERT INTO jobrouter.dbo.zt_ara_sitzungen (newID2, name, datum) SELECT MAX(newID2) + 1, testttt, 2021-10-07 00:00:00 FROM jobrouter.dbo.zt_ara_sitzungen]
[Native code: 0]
[Native message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error]
```

I searched for answeres here but all I could find seem to have to do with placeholders or pdo which I don't use (at least I think so).

Also, what is this COUNT field?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You place PHP variables directly into the SQL query (which is a no-go in itself)... but Strings must be quoted properly, which isn't the case here

Comment: `MAX(newID2) + 1` has a code smell of a design flaw to it; why are you not using an `IDENTITY` or `SEQUENCE`? `$sitzungsname, $sitzungsdatum` has a code smell of a huge security vulnerability; SQL Injection. I would start by fixing your design *and* your parametrisation, and then seeing if you still get the same error (which I doubt you will).

Comment: Completely agree that `MAX(id)+1` is generally unsafe due to parallelism and race conditions.  Just use `IDENTITY` columns *(for SQL Server)*.  Then fix the parameterisation *(partly for security, partly for ensuring data types are encoded and quoted correctly)*.  Once you've addressed those two issues, if there's still a problem, check for triggers on your table.

Comment: Thanks! The plattform I'm using translates the PHP-variables into pure text/date before running the query and also checks for code in variables which it would block. But I will check for IDENTITY and see!

Comment: *"I'm using translates the PHP-variables into pure text/date before running the query"* And is a massive security vulnerability; don't inject your parameters **parametrise** them... This can be **clearly** seen in your error as the SQL being run hasn't properly quoted your string literal `testttt`; because it was **injected** *not* parametrised.